# ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable - Tensorflow 2.0

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, tensorflow2.0, generative-adversarial-network

I'm trying to find the corresponding latent code of a MNIST image from a well-trained MNIST GAN model. What I plan to do is to apply gradient descent on the loss defined as the distance between the target and the generated sample. As the generated sample gets closer to the target, the loss decreases, and the corresponding latent code is what I need.

Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.keras import Model
from tensorflow.keras import Sequential
import tensorflow.keras.backend as K
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
from tensorflow.keras import layers
from tensorflow.keras.layers import *
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import Adam
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers import SGD
from tensorflow.keras.losses import MeanSquaredError
import random

### Load MNIST data
(data_x, _), _ = mnist.load_data()
data_x = np.reshape(np.asarray(data_x), [60000, 28*28]).astype(float)
train = data_x[:1024]
test = data_x[-10:]

### GAN setting
generator = Sequential([
    Dense(7 * 7 * 64, input_shape=[100]),
    BatchNormalization(),
    LeakyReLU(),
    Reshape([7, 7, 64]),
    UpSampling2D([2, 2]),
    Conv2DTranspose(64, [3, 3], padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    LeakyReLU(),
    UpSampling2D([2, 2]),
    Conv2DTranspose(1, [3, 3], padding='same', activation='sigmoid')
])

discriminator = Sequential([
    Conv2D(64, [3, 3], padding='same', input_shape=[28, 28, 1]),
    BatchNormalization(),
    LeakyReLU(),
    MaxPool2D([2, 2]),
    Conv2D(64, [3, 3], padding='same'),
    BatchNormalization(),
    LeakyReLU(),
    MaxPool2D([2, 2]),
    Flatten(),
    Dense(128),
    BatchNormalization(),
    LeakyReLU(),
    Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
])

x_input = Input([28, 28, 1])
g_sample_input = Input([100])

log_clip = Lambda(lambda x: K.log(x + 1e-3))

sample_score = discriminator(generator(g_sample_input))

d_loss = (
    - log_clip(discriminator(x_input)) 
    - log_clip(1.0 - sample_score)
)
fit_discriminator = Model(inputs=[x_input, g_sample_input], outputs=d_loss)
fit_discriminator.add_loss(d_loss)
generator.trainable = False
for layer in generator.layers:
    if isinstance(layer, BatchNormalization):
        layer.trainable = True
fit_discriminator.compile(optimizer=Adam(0.001))
generator.trainable = True

g_loss = (
    - log_clip(sample_score)
)
fit_generator = Model(inputs=g_sample_input, outputs=g_loss)
fit_generator.add_loss(g_loss)
discriminator.trainable = False
for layer in discriminator.layers:
    if isinstance(layer, BatchNormalization):
        layer.trainable = True
fit_generator.compile(optimizer=Adam(0.001))
discriminator.trainable = True

### GAN training
train_x = train.reshape([-1, 28, 28, 1]) / 255
batch_size = 64
for i in range(10000):
    x = train_x[random.sample(range(len(train_x)), batch_size)]
    g_sample = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, [batch_size, 100])
    fit_discriminator.fit([K.constant(x), K.constant(g_sample)])
    fit_generator.fit(g_sample)
    
### Search for latent code
target = (test[0] / 255).reshape([28, 28])
mse = MeanSquaredError()
z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, [1, 100])
z_t = tf.Variable(z, trainable=True)
opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.1)

for _ in range(10):
    loss_fn = lambda: mse(target,
                          generator(z_t.numpy())[0].numpy().reshape([28, 28]))

    opt.minimize(loss_fn, var_list=[z_t])
```

And I get this error:

> ValueError: No gradients provided for any variable: ['Variable:0'].

It seems that Tensorflow cannot calculate the gradient from this kind of loss.

Is there a way to calculate the gradient if the loss is derived from another model? Or is there a way to achieve my goal without calculating the gradient?

Comment: Your code does not reproduce the error you've posted. See how to create a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thank you for the comment. This is my first time asking question here and sorry for the lack of information. I have updated the code so that everything is provided.

Comment: No apology necessary, just trying to help you ask an efficient question. There are a lot of posts to this site every minute and if we can copy and paste your code, and it reproduces the error, the probability of someone being able to answer is drastically higher than if it doesn't :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the key point.

Tensorflow calculates gradients based on the graph. So we should always put every operations inside the graph.

The error of my code is caused by the tensor-numpy transformation. Since once we transform the tensor to a numpy array, it is brought out of the graph and Tensorflow can not track it anymore.

This is my new code and it runs well now:

```
mse = MeanSquaredError()
target = (test[0] / 255).reshape([28, 28])
target_t = tf.convert_to_tensor(target)
z = np.random.uniform(-1, 1, [1, 100])
z_t = tf.Variable(z, trainable=True)
opt = SGD(learning_rate=0.1)

for _ in range(10):
    loss_fn = lambda: mse(target_t,
                          tf.reshape(tf.cast(generator(z_t), tf.float64), [28, 28]))
    opt.minimize(loss_fn, var_list=[z_t])
```

(only the last piece of the code is shown here, the other part remains the same.)